# Jquery ajax function working in IE but not in FF

Tags: jquery, ajax

Okay I have this ajax call

```
$('.updatecom .registercomplaint').click(function(){
    updatecomplaints();
});
```

This calls the function updatecomplaints()

```
function updatecomplaints()
{
var tno = $(".updatecom #tno").val();
var status = $(".updatecom #status").val();
if(status=='DONE')
{
    $(".updatecom #con").val('');
}
var tname = $(".updatecom #tname").val();
var rg11 = $(".updatecom #crg11").val();
var rg06 = $(".updatecom #crg06").val();
var tvpins = $(".updatecom #tvpins").val();
var jointer = $(".updatecom #jointer").val();
var cquantity = $(".updatecom #conqty").val();
var nooftv = $(".updatecom #tvno").val();
var misc = $(".updatecom #misc").val();
var tcomments = $(".updatecom #tcomments").val();
var con = $(".updatecom #con").val();
//alert(tno+status+tname+rg11+rg06+tvpins+jointer+cquantity+nooftv+misc+tcomments+con);
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "up_functions.php",
    data: "ticket="+ tno +"& opt=upcom" +"& status="+ status +"& tname="+ tname +"& rg11="+ rg11 +"& rg06="+ rg06 +"& tvpins="+ tvpins +"& jointer="+ jointer +"& cquantity="+ cquantity +"& nooftv="+ nooftv +"& misc="+ misc +"& tcomments="+ tcomments +"& con="+ con,
    success: function(response)
    {
        alert(response);

    }
});
```

}

here is my up_functions.php

```
$tno = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['ticket']));
        $status = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['status']));
        $tname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['tname']));
        $rg11 = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['rg11']));
        $rg06 = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['rg06']));
        $tvpins = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['tvpins']));
        $jointer = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['jointer']));
        $cquantity = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['cquantity']));
        $nooftv = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['nooftv']));
        $misc = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['misc']));
        $tcomments = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['tcomments']));
        $con = htmlspecialchars(trim($_REQUEST['con']));
        $result=$ptr->upcomticketinfo($tno,$status,$tname,$rg11,$rg06,$tvpins,$jointer,$cquantity,$nooftv,$misc,$tcomments,$con);
        echo $result;
```

and here is my upconticketinfo() php function

```
function upcomticketinfo($tno,$status,$tname,$rg11,$rg06,$tvpins,$jointer,$cquantity,$nooftv,$misc,$tcomments,$con)
{
    if($con!='' || $con!=NULL)
    {
        $this->query = "update `booking discription` set `STATUS`='$status',`CLOSED ON`='$con' where `TICKET NO`='$tno'"; 
        $this->q_result = mysql_query($this->query,$this->conn) or die(mysql_error());
        if($this->q_result)
        {
            $query = "update `tech detail` set `TECH NAME`='$tname',`CABLE RG11`='$rg11',`CABLE RG06`='$rg06',`TV PINS USED`='$tvpins',`JOINTER USED`='$jointer',`CONNECTOR QTY`='$cquantity',`NO OF TV`='$nooftv',`MISC`='$misc',`TECH COMMENTS`='$tcomments' where `BOOKING`='$tno'"; 
            $q_result = mysql_query($query,$this->conn) or die(mysql_error());
            if($q_result)
            {
                $response = "updated";
            }
            else
            {
                $response = "error";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $response = "error";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->query = "update `booking discription` set `STATUS`='$status' where `TICKET NO`='$tno'"; 
        $this->q_result = mysql_query($this->query,$this->conn) or die(mysql_error());
        if($this->q_result)
        {
            $query = "update `tech detail` set `TECH NAME`='$tname',`CABLE RG11`='$rg11',`CABLE RG06`='$rg06',`TV PINS USED`='$tvpins',`JOINTER USED`='$jointer',`CONNECTOR QTY`='$cquantity',`NO OF TV`='$nooftv',`MISC`='$misc',`TECH COMMENTS`='$tcomments' where `BOOKING`='$tno'"; 
            $q_result = mysql_query($query,$this->conn) or die(mysql_error());
            if($q_result)
            {
                $response = "updated";
            }
            else
            {
                $response = "error";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $response = "error";
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Question is that, this code is working just fine in IE8 i.e i am using... but it is not working in FF 3.6.3...
I have checked each n everything...
One thing is that the code works fine on FF too only when i activate the firebug debugger. Otherwise the alert in ajax success shows itself with nothing in it...
Help me...

Comment: does firefox display any error?

Comment: please visit faq... http://stackoverflow.com/faq Welcome to SO...

Comment: @Ghommey... No firefox does not show any error.... plus if i use firebug debugger, the alert shows 'updated' message.... when i de-activate firebug... same old story starts again

Comment: possible duplicate of [May be my example site may answer my question about ajax call... Help me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995105/may-be-my-example-site-may-answer-my-question-about-ajax-call-help-me)

Answer (score 2):

if this is not a typo, it's the problem...

```
data: "ticket="+ tno +"& opt=upcom" +"& status="+ status +"& tname="+ tname +"& rg11="+ rg11 +"& rg06="+ rg06 +"& tvpins="+ tvpins +"& jointer="+ jointer +"& cquantity="+ cquantity +"& nooftv="+ nooftv +"& misc="+ misc +"& tcomments="+ tcomments +"& con="+ con
```

you have extra space after each &....

and if I were you, i'd do it this way...

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "up_functions.php",
    data: {
           "ticket":tno,
           "opt":"upcom",
           "status":status,
           "tname":tname,
           "rg11":rg11,
           "rg06":rg06,
           "tvpins":tvpins,
           "jointer":jointer,
           "cquantity":cquantity,
           "nooftv":nooftv,
           "misc":misc,
           "tcomments":tcomments,
           "con":con 
    },
    success: function(response)
    {
        alert(response);

    }
});
```

would be easier to read...

Comment: @jAndy - that's what I learned here in SO... be quick in the eye... ;)

Comment: I think in my up_functions file, i am using "htmlspecialchars(trim" function which handles all the extra spacing etc from the data string

Comment: check that with Firebug -> post/request header

Comment: @Reigel I changed it like this...

data: ({ticket: tno ,opt: upcom, status: status, tname: tname, rg11: rg11, rg06: rg06, tvpins: tvpins, jointer: jointer, cquantity: cquantity, nooftv: nooftv, misc: misc, tcomments: tcomments, con: con}),

but still no luck

Comment: @Reigel....Still no luck bro...
{"ticket": tno , "opt": "upcom", "status": status, "tname": tname, "rg11": rg11, "rg06": rg06, "tvpins": tvpins, "jointer": jointer, "cquantity": cquantity, "nooftv": nooftv, "misc": misc, "tcomments": tcomments, "con": con}

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data do you expect from the server?

Try adding

```
dataType: 'text'
```

to your .ajax() request, for instance.

If thats not the issue, give Reigel's answer a shot. I'd strongly recommend to use

```
$.ajax({
  data: {
       ticket:   tno,
       opt:      upcom,
       status:   status,
       ...
  }
});
```

Comment: very strange, what does your server say? Does it receive the request from Firefox?

Comment: @jAndy
when i click update button then Net->XHR gives this
URL -> POST up_functions.php (red color)
status -> Aborted (red color)
domain -> localhost (red color)
size -> ? (red color)